# Error while updating in terminal

Tags: 15.04

Im was trying to do the update command `sudo apt-get update` and the error comes. Whats wrong? Please help me.

Error:

```
W: mistake by getting ppa.launchpad.net/aapo-rantalainen/games/ubuntu/dists/vivid/… 404 not Found 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored or old used in their place .#
```

Comment: Please translate into English :)

Comment: W: mistake by getting http://ppa.launchpad.net/aapo-rantalainen/games/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 not Found E: Some index files failed to download . They have been ignored or old used in their place .#

Comment: Sounds like he needs to delete a bad ppa repository

Comment: Thanks but which ppa repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~aapo-rantalainen/+archive/ubuntu/games#) `ppa:aapo-rantalainen/games` has no Vivid packages.

Remove the PPA:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aapo-rantalainen-ubuntu-games-vivid.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, really nice to have a great community like this! :)